# Why dialog form hangs up application after Application.Exit() call?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a Windows Forms application with main form showing data grid and "details form" appearing after double-clicking one of rows (using `ShowDialog` method). This "details form" is giving me some troubles, precisely:

1. During long synchronous call to web service system sets form in "not responding" state. After callback form hides behind main window. Other than that everything works fine.
2. In some situations I need to immediately close aplication using `Application.Exit`. When "details form" is open application just hangs up. Even `Environment.Exit` or `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort` don't work.

I wonder if basing on those symptoms you can give me any tips, what can be wrong. I would give some code examples, but I don't know what can be significant in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If immediately closing the application is part of project requirement, then you can't let long synchronous calls block your abort/exit code. Move long synchronous calls to background threads.

Comment: I see that didn't describe it clearly enough. Points 1. and 2. are not connected, at least not directly.

Comment: well set a break point at your abort/exit code (point A), and another right after your web service call (point B) and debug.  You will see you can't hit point A until you pass point B, but your requirement is to hit point A before point B, so you need to modify the synchronous call to be asynchronous.

Comment: I mean that I don't need to call web service for application to hang up. It's enough for "details form" to be open. I only thought that this peculiar behaviour after service callback may be another symptom of the same mistake in implementation.

Comment: What Application.Exit does is to post a WM_QUIT message. But you are running another message pump (the modal form) thus the message is ignored See Raymond's Modality, part 3: The WM_QUIT message for details. You shouldn't really need Application.Exit by the way, because when a modal form is open, the user is expecting the main window's close button is disabled just like the rest of main window.